# Why is a CO single bond stronger than a NO single bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, electronegativity

Why is a CO sigma bond stronger than a NO sigma bond? I would think that since nitrogen and oxygen are of similar size and have similar atomic orbitals (because they are adjacent in the period), their MO "overlap" would be superior.
Does it have something to do with their similar electronegativities "fighting" over the electrons?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is just the extra electrons. Think of F... or better yet, think of Ne; it has the same size and same orbitals, so why is there no $\ce{Ne2}$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Octet rule. I'm not sure what point you are making here. C-O sigma bond has a greater bond energy than a N-O single bond. What "extra electrons" are you referring to?

Comment: How many valence electrons are there in a CO molecule? How many are in NO?

Comment: What "single bond"? You mean sigma bonds in CO and NO molecules?

Comment: @Mithoron exactly

Comment: @Mithoron Could it be that the larger electronegativity difference between C and O means that there is more negative charge sitting on the oxygen, thus making a stronger electrostatic bond between the two atoms?